# how to specify pattern more exactly with regexp

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to reduce a dataframe with a lot of duplicates into a dataframe with every particular entry only one time, but with a variable called "counter" how often this variable occurs in the dataframe. Now I have some troubles with regular expressions..

```
length(grep(kh$gem[124],kh$gem))
```

counts how often `kh$gem[124]` is in the dataframe. The problem is that

```
> kh$gem[124]
[1] "Salzburg"
```

and

```
  > grep(kh$gem[124],kh$gem)
  [1] 120 124 125 126 127 128 134 141 144 146 148
```

but if i look into these variables there are some I which indeed 'match' the regexp, but are not exactly those I am searching for.

```
 > kh$gem[c(120,124,125,126,127,128,134,141,144,146,148)]
[1] "Oberndorf bei Salzburg" "Salzburg" "Salzburg" "Salzburg"              
[5] "Salzburg" "Salzburg" "Salzburg" "Salzburg"              
[9] "Salzburg" "Oberndorf bei Salzburg" "Salzburg"
```

How can I eliminate those which are "Oberndorf bei Salzburg"?

Thanks for help. Best regards!

Comment: `sum(kh$gem %in% kh$gem[124])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add anchors.

```
grep(paste0("^" , kh$gem[124] , "$"),kh$gem)
```